# Rails Routes for API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create the following Routes

```
/plans
/plans/:plan_id/notes
/plans/:plan_id/notes/:id

/notes/:note_id/reply
/notes/:note_id/upvote
```

This is my Route file

```
resources :plans, only: [:create, :index, :show] do
  resource :note, only: [:create]
  resources :notes, only: [:destroy]
end

resources :notes, only: [:index] do
  resource :note_replies, only: [:create, :destroy]
  resources :note_upvotes, only: [:create, :destroy]
end
```

Is there a way to remove duplication of routes created for notes?

Comment: What kind of duplication you are trying to avoid? I guess you asked about *route concerns*? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-concerns

Comment: I don't think there is duplication there. The routes might have same paths, but they should respond to different HTTP verbs.